# Automatically move files to an external drive when it's available

Tags: macos, airport-extreme, network-drive

I have an networked drive connected to an Airport Extreme, so it's available whenever I'm on my home wifi network.  I'd like to automatically move files from a specific folder to a specific folder on the networked drive when it's available.  What's the best way to automate this?

Comment: I messed around with [Hazel](http://www.noodlesoft.com/hazel.php) and it works but will display a Growl error if it tries to move files when the external drive is unavailable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set `launchd` to monitor `/Volumes` as a WatchPath, it can run a script every time a drive is mounted. Simply make this script one that checks if your Airport Extreme drive is mounted then runs the copy if it is. For instance:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -e /Volumes/AirportExtremeDriveName ]
    rsync -aE /a/specific/folder/ /Volumes/AirportExtremeDriveName/another/specific/folder/
fi
```

I suggest `rsync` as it's smart enough to not copy files that are the same in both the source and the destination, which will speed things up no end. If you add the `-delete` argument, any files that no longer exist in the source will be deleted from the destination.

At no extra cost, here's the `launchd` script. Save the following in `~/Library/LaunchAgents/some.meaningful.name.plist`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>some.meaningful.name</string>

    <key>LowPriorityIO</key>
    <true/>

    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/where/you/saved/your/script.sh</string>
    </array>

    <key>WatchPaths</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Volumes</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Then, load the `launchd` job with:

```
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/some.meaningful.name.plist
```

It'll be loaded automatically when you log in and unloaded when you log out.